# Posting article/tutorial on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know SO allows to share knowledge Q&A style. Do you think it is a suitable place to write a tutorial? I tried searching for similar questions, but the answers were not conclusive.
I am struggling with creating ASP.NET MVC 6 app with Angular2. There are blog posts about this, but they don't cover latest Angular2 RC release, which changed things a bit. I have it almost figured out, so I thought of sharing my knowledge. I do not own a blog and there is no point in starting one since I don't know when I'll have something else to share with the community. Do you think it would be ok to write an article explaining in details how to setup ASP .NET MVC 6 project with Angular2 RC on StackOverflow?

Comment: Hi Emsi, First thing `stackoverflow` is not that platform which you are looking for. `Stackoverflow` is not for `blog` purpose.  Its a Community for Q&A. If your looking for platform where you can share your own knowledge, for this there are various ways you can do this, like : You can Create your own blog and post an article on that, You can create your profile on `Code Project` OR `C-SharpCorner` These are most famous platform where you can write your own blogs. If you want to create your video tutorial you can upload on `YouTube`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think it is a suitable place to write a tutorial?

No, it isn't. The format is a single question (with a limited scope - it should be answerable within a few paragraphs), with the best answer at the top. Tutorials are not structured in this manner.